# Why do we need quantum decoherence to explain the quantum to classical transition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, decoherence, quantum-measurements

Why is decoherence necessary to explain the transition from quantum to classical...

If we left out decoherence, what does quantum mechanics predict about the behavior of classical objects? My point being... what would QM without decoherence predict about macroscopic behavior? (I assume it would predict something contrary to what we normally see, which is why we need decoherence).

I mean if we're talking about why we don't observe superpositions, isn't that taken care of by wave function collapse? Described by postulate 3 here:

http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/notes/quantrev/node20.html

So I'm confused as to what decoherence is supposed to explain?

So as an example... suppose I throw a baseball... if there was no decoherence, what would I observe?

EDIT: To elaborate on my confusion. Here's an article:

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/1999/02/990202072053.htm

He says: ""Quantum mechanics without decoherence leads to a universe of paradoxes -- there is a real conflict." What paradoxes is he referring to here? Not sure what paradoxes decoherence is preventing.

Comment: There's no such thing as "QM without decoherence". To leave out decoherence, you'd need to pick from a handful of competing alternative theories to get any predictions at all. Wavefunction collapse on the other hand (in so far as it means more than just decoherence) is a product of a time when QM was still in development meaning people did not understand it as well.

Comment: But there was a time when physicists started talking about decoherence... before that they didn't. What was the reason they started talking about it? You're saying that decoherence wasn't necessary to explain anything?

Comment: This wiki page says decoherence was introduced in 1970: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence

Comment: Ok... maybe if I put it like this... the way I understand it decoherence is due to some interaction with the environment. So let's suppose as a thought experiment... I throw a baseball and then remove the environment... how will the baseball behave without any environment to interact with?

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying the theory of quantum mechanics works without decoherence... I'm talking simply about the expectations of scientists, and why they started talking about decoherence in the first place. You guys seem to think I'm implying something about the theory... that's not my point at all. I'm trying to understand what decoherence is by comparing it to what was expected before the scientists understood decoherence.

Comment: Regarding the baseball comment: an isolated baseball is a pretty good environment by itself. Decoherence is the name we give situations involving a quantum superposition of terms whose interference could never be observed in practice because they differ from each other in hopelessly complicated ways. An isolated baseball is already plenty complicated enough to preclude doing anything like a double-slit interference experiment using a baseball as the "particle," with or without any external environment.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly, ok thanks. So it's impossible to talk about how a baseball would behave "without decoherence" even as a thought experiment? I'm just trying to figure out what decoherence is supposed to explain with regards to the quantum->classical transition. I don't see how to understand this without knowing something about how macroscopic objects would behave without dechoerence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129224/discussion-between-ameet-sharma-and-chiral-anomaly).

Comment: [Decoherence does *not* explain the transition from quantum to classical](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-decoherence/#ConApp)

Comment: It explains the parts that don't depend on the dubious claim that there *is* a fundamental transition from quantum to classical.